# R: Merge multiple irregular time series with zoo by averaging

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

```
library(zoo)
a <- read.zoo(data.frame(t = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), v = c(20, 20.5, 21, 20.7, 22, 19.6)))
b <- read.zoo(data.frame(t = c(1, 1.3, 2.4, 2.7, 5.3, 6, 6.9), v = c(15, 15.2, 11, 20.3, 12, 12.6, 20)))
```

`merge(a, b)` will do:

```
       a    b
1   20.0 15.0
1.3   NA 15.2
2   20.5   NA
2.4   NA 11.0
2.7   NA 20.3
3   21.0   NA
4   20.7   NA
5   22.0   NA
5.3   NA 12.0
6   19.6 12.6
6.9   NA 20.0
```

What I need is the average across `a` and `b` assuming that column `v` represents a value that remains constant between successive time samples:

```
       a    b     **desired output**
1   20.0 15.0         17.50
1.3   NA 15.2         17.60
2   20.5   NA         17.85
2.4   NA 11.0         15.75
2.7   NA 20.3         20.40
3   21.0   NA         20.65
4   20.7   NA         20.50
5   22.0   NA         21.15
5.3   NA 12.0         17.00
6   19.6 12.6         16.10
6.9   NA 20.0         19.80
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- merge(a, b)
rowMeans(na.locf(x))
[1] 17.50 17.60 17.85 15.75 20.40 20.65 20.50 21.15 17.00 16.10 19.80
```